# How to get input type value using ionic2?

Tags: ionic2

I am new to the ionic framework, When i was entering the input type button it is going to the bottom of the page. How can i overcome these error.
Below is my code:

```
<ion-header></ion-header>
 <ion-content padding>
  <h2></h2>
   <div>
      <img class="displayed"  style="height:100px; width:100px text-align: center;" src="assets/img/logo.png">
      <h2>Forgot Password</h2>
  </div>
    <p class="side" style= "margin-top:90px; color:grey;  font-size:18px; font-family:'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif">Enter the Phone number associated with your account, and we'll send an OTP to reset your password</p>
<ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>PHONE</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="number" value="" ></ion-input>
<input type="number" placeholder="8121218820" ng-model="data.number" 
 required>
  </ion-item>
  <button ion-button color="secondary" round>SEND OTP</button>
 </ion-content>
```

Below is my screen image:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean? Is "When i was entering the input type button it is going to the bottom of the page" this your problem? Or is "How to get input type value using ionic2?" this the problem? And what 'error' are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I really did not understand your question but

but in your code above if you are using the

```
<ion-input type="number" value="" ></ion-input>
```

then why are you again using  input type="number" placeholder="8121218820" ng-model="data.number" 
 required>

what is that all about besides if you are using ionic2 you are also using angular2 in conjunction

its not ng-model

```
<ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="data.number"></ion-input>
```

also set a default value for field values in ionviewdidload function or in the constructor not in your view